# Постановка тире перед союзом "как"

Tags: пунктуация, тире, обороты-с-как

В предложении по типу "Арест - как способ выбить долги" требуется ли тире перед сравнительным союзом? Разногласия родились при написании предложения "Временное тату как наружная реклама". С коллегой не сошлись во мнениях: он считает, что здесь есть расхождение по смыслам ( первое - уточнение, второй вариант - сравнение), я считаю, что правила едины для написания сравнительного оборота в этих двух случаях - без тире. Рассудите, пожалуйста, кто из нас прав

Answer (score 1):

Ни в первом случае, ни во втором **тире перед "как" не требуется**.

И там, и там действует следующее правило:

> Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) *как, словно, будто,
> точно, как будто, что* не выделяются запятыми в следующих случаях:
> ...при передаче значения «в качестве» (оборот является частью
> сказуемого): *Сергей **Лазо** был прислан комитетом **как главнокомандующий***
> (Фад.); ...*Тамара Ивановна поняла этот **голос как** посланное ей вдогонку
> **прощание*** (Расп.)

[(Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации, справочник под ред.
Лопатина, раздел "Путнктуация", § 90.)](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg90.php)

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!